# How to reference query results from multiple SlamData queries?

Tags: mongodb, slamdata

In trying to chart MongoDB data with SlamData my data is such that I need multiple SQL2 queries in order to get it into the format I need for my chart, so my cards currently look like;

My MongoDB Collection > Query1 > Preview Table > Query1 > Preview Table

I am using SQL2 syntax similar to "select * from :results" in Query1 (obviously I'm doing more than select *!) so my question is how do I reference the results from Query1 in Query2?

If I use "from :results" in Query2 I am accessing the MongoDB collection and not the results from Query1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, have you found a solution?